# First and Second occurrence in string Python

Tags: python, string

I have an inputted string that may contain letter 'f'.
If the word contains no fs, print -1;
if there’s only one f in the word, print its index;
if it occurs twice or more times, print the indexes of two first occurrences.

For example if we have the word office the output should be -->   1 2

I have tried:

```
if s.find('f') > 0:
  if s.find('f').count() >= 2:
    print(s.find('f'))
  if s.find('f').count() == 1:
    print(s.find('f'))
else:
  print(-1)
```

Comment: please add your attempted codes

Comment: I have added one of my attempted cods but It is not a very good one . I know I can't use count() with string but I just don't come up with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Call `str.index()` with the offset + length of the previous match as the start index to find the next occurrence of a substring:

```
def find_indices(string_value, term):
    indices = []
    offset = 0
    while offset < len(string_value):
        try:
            idx = string_value.index(term, offset)
            indices.append(idx)
            offset = idx + len(term)
        except ValueError:
            break
    return indices

print(find_indices('office', 'f'))
```

Which prints `[1, 2]`

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think this is a little bit complicated solution. I mean I am very new to Python and even it is not allowed to use functions. Additionally, I have to solve the problem with only inputted string s and maybe Conditions, String slicing, for loop, List Comprehensions or String methods.

Comment: @AlbinaHakobyan I'm afraid I can't read minds, you should [add this information to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73855940/edit) :)