# How to find n-th largest number with O(N) solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, big-o

Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code:

**Problem Description**: Your program first receives an integer n and then a list of float values. Print the n-th largest element in the list with one decimal point precision.

Note: n-th largest, not just n-th element. And N is the length of the list.

Example input: `2 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0` output: `4.0`

```
numbers = input()
a = numbers.split() 
n = int(a[0]) 
b = sorted(a[1:])
n_th_largest =float(b[-n]) 
e = "{:.1f}".format(n_th_largest)
print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code

You sort the *strings*, so for example `'2.0'` will be regarded as larger than `'13.0'`, because the character `'2'` is larger than the character `'1'`. So you'll get a wrong order and thus a wrong result.

One way to sort by `float` value is with a key function:

```
b = sorted(a[1:], key=float)
```

Or convert to floats first and then just sort those floats:

```
b = sorted(map(float, a[1:]))
```

In this case, you don't need the extra conversion to float in the next line.

---

As for O(N) ... it's *possible*, as shown [almost 50 years ago](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/BFPRT73.pdf), but far from trivial. Not easy to do even if you already know how to do it. And the problem description doesn't actually ask for it. But if you want to do it, have a look at Wikipedia's [Selection algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) page or that paper or an introductory algorithms textbook that covers the subject, for example CLRS's [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

Answer (score -2):

You can use [count sort](https://favtutor.com/blogs/counting-sort-python) for O(n) time complexity and O(n) memory based on a range of possible values. It is essentially a hashing technique. Note that it is impossible to do O(n) in time complexity and O(1) memory. Here's some code from the linked source:

```
# python program for counting sort

def countingSort(arr):
    size = len(arr)
    output = [0] * size

    # count array initialization
    count = [0] * 10

    # storing the count of each element 
    for m in range(0, size):
        count[arr[m]] += 1

    # storing the cumulative count
    for m in range(1, 10):
        count[m] += count[m - 1]

    # place the elements in output array after finding the index of each element of original array in count array
    m = size - 1
    while m >= 0:
        output[count[arr[m]] - 1] = arr[m]
        count[arr[m]] -= 1
        m -= 1

    for m in range(0, size):
        arr[m] = output[m]

data = [3,5,1,6,7,8,3]
countingSort(data)
print("Sorted Array: ")
print(data)
```

Comment: I “plagiarized” it from the source linked. I didn’t make the algorithm but now you know it exists

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO: It's real. It's not general purpose because it's not `O(n)` in memory, it's `O(n)` memory based on the *range* of possible values. So if your values can occupy a space of 2 trillion, then you need that much memory, even if you just have two values, and you need to *know* the bounded range to start with. Useful when meaningfully range-constricted, useless otherwise.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the fun fact is that the OP doesn't know that kind of things, she didn't even know what a try/except block was, and she found "little bit complicated" one simple piece of code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73855940/first-and-second-occurrence-in-string-python), so I don't think she will understand immediately this dozens of comments in this threads lol

Comment: @asultan904 I would include part of your first comment in the answer, it's useful. Anyway I didn't downvote.

Comment: While count sort could be used to solve the task, just by itself it does not. Note that since the input is `float`, not `int`, just getting the `count` both correct and space efficient is non-trivial.